# How to load environment variable from a file for an upstart job?

Tags: upstart, environment-variables

I'm writing an upstart job for a service that is configured using environment variables, and a lot of them (> 20).

The way this was handled so far was usually to run it from a Ruby launcher that used Ruby's Dotenv gem to load the configuration file. I want to replace the launcher with a straight forward upstart file (to reduce the amount of custom code I need to maintain) but I ran into the problem of how to set up all the environment variables needed by service.

My initial take was:

```
script
   . /etc/default/service-conf
   /usr/local/bin/service
end script
```

but just sourcing the file doesn't export the variables, and I don't want to add a lot of `export` commands to the script, mainly as it will be completely unmaintainable and unreadable mess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to tackle the problem of exporting variables defined in a source file, including all kinds of hacks (for example, the weird `export $(cat file | xargs)` hack [documented in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331497/set-environment-variables-from-file)), but the simplest way to just enable "Mark variables for export" flag in your shell, before sourcing the environment file.

[Here is the bash documentation for this feature - look under `-a`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html).

While the `script` tag in upstart does not use Bash as a shell - it uses the default POSIX shell implementation in Ubuntu, called [dash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) which also support this feature, calling it `allexport`. So the upstart script section should read:

```
script
  set -a
  . /etc/default/service-conf
  /usr/local/bin/service
end script
```